# Gradle: read latest xy-release GIT tag for versioning

Tags: git, ant, versioning, gradle

I'm currently migrating a project from ant to gradle. Everything is fine, only one problem exists: currently we have a custom ant-contrib based task for executing the git command on the repo to read the latest xy-release tag to get the version number (and version the generated jar filename like project-xy.jar).
As I can see, I need some plugin for this. Sadly, looking thru the available plugins, nothing really can help me (there exists some git-related plugins, but their goal is something else, like *making* a release, so tagging the repo, not reading the already-made tags).
So I need help on reaching my goal. Do I have to invent the whole thing in Gradle? I know I can import existing ant build files, but I don't really want to.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I tried to implement the same old stuff in Gradle. (because I'm fleeing from ant/ivy, so I don't want to keep old stuff). Here is the output (might be lame, because I'm new to Gradle and Groovy). It works.

```
jar {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime

    // get the version
    doFirst {
        new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { execOS ->
            def result = exec {
                executable = 'git'
                args = [ 'describe', '--tags', '--match', '[0-9]*-release', '--dirty=-dirty' ]
                standardOutput = execOS
            }

            // calculate version information
            def buildVersion = execOS.toString().trim().replaceAll("-release", "")
            def buildVersionMajor = buildVersion.replaceAll("^(\\d+).*\$", "\$1")
            def buildVersionMinor = buildVersion.replaceAll("^\\d+\\.(\\d+).*\$", "\$1")
            def buildVersionRev = buildVersion.replaceAll("^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.(\\d+).*\$", "\$1")
            def buildTag = buildVersion.replaceAll("^[^-]*-(.*)\$", "\$1").replaceAll("^(.*)-dirty\$", "\$1")
            def dirty = buildVersion.endsWith("dirty")

            println("Version: " + buildVersion)
            println("Major: " + buildVersionMajor)
            println("Minor: " + buildVersionMinor)
            println("Revision: " + buildVersionRev)
            println("Tag: " + buildTag)
            println("Dirty: " + dirty)

            // name the jar file
            version buildVersion
        }
    }

    // include dependencies into jar
    def classpath  = configurations.runtime.collect { it.directory ? it : zipTree(it) }
    from (classpath) {
        exclude 'META-INF/**'
    }

    // manifest definition
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'your.fancy.MainClass'
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, just reuse the existing Ant task. No need to import the Ant build.

Answer (score 0):

Since git has command for this, `git describe`, it should be pretty trivial. Just call to git and read in the output. To get just the last *-release tag, the exact command is

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --match=*-release
```

(I am not sure whether it's regex or glob; if it's regex, it would need `.*-release`). Add `--tags` if your release tags are not annotated.